# Check absolute paths in Python

Tags: python, path

How can I check whether two file paths point to the same file in Python?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$ touch foo
$ ln -s foo bar
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path.samefile)
Help on function samefile in module posixpath:

samefile(f1, f2)
    Test whether two pathnames reference the same actual file

>>> os.path.samefile("foo", "bar")
True
```

Comment: Nice answer.  I didn not know about this method!

Comment: Note that this is documented as only available on Unix. It is not present on Windows, at least in Python 2.6.

Comment: for windows, you can approximate the behaviour with `os.stat('foo') == os.stat('bar')`

Comment: Note: This only seems to work if the file actually exists. When they are hypothetical (e.g. checking whether a target destination already exists before copying a file), an abspath comparison is they way to go.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [`os.path.abspath(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) to normalize each path for comparison.

```
os.path.abspath(foo) == os.path.abspath(bar)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple string compare should work:

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(first) == os.path.abspath(second)
```

Credit to Andrew, he corrected my initial post which included a call to `os.path.normpath`: this is unneeded because the implementation of `os.path.abspath` does it for you.

Comment: You don't need to call `normpath` first.

Comment: Andrew: if you were just going to compare the strings you may end up with different paths pointing to the same file in some cases.  os.abspath doesnt do anything clever, it only adds a prefix.

Comment: @Andrew: no i take it back!  You were right, for *nix at least the implementation does that for you.  Every day is a schoolday :)

Comment: I disagree, from http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html:  Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path. On most platforms, this is equivalent to normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path)).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows systems, there is no `samefile` function and you also have to worry about case. The `normcase` function from `os.path` can be combined with `abspath` to handle this case.

```
from os.path import abspath, normcase

def are_paths_equivalent(path1, path2):
    return normcase(abspath(path1)) == normcase(abspath(path2))
```

This will consider "C:\SPAM\Eggs.txt" to be equivalent to "c:\spam\eggs.txt" on Windows.

Note that unlike `samefile`, all methods based on normalizing and comparing paths will not be aware of cases where completely different paths refer to the same file. On Windows, this means that if you use SUBST, MKLINK or mounted network shares to create multiple distinct paths to the same file, none of these solutions will be able to say "that's the same file". Hopefully that's not too much of a problem most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

May be one can use os.path.relpath(path1, path2) as workaround for os.path.samefile(path1, path2) on Windows?

If os.path.relpath(path1, path2) returns '.' than path1 and path2 point to the same place